# Плохая ли практика изменять входных параметров методом?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, best-practice

Некоторые ЯП позволяют менять объекты, переданные в методы в качестве аргументов. Но это может вызывать очень много сайд эффектов, которые другой программист, работающий с кодом просто не ожидает.

Вот пример на *JS*

```
let hierarchy = []; // Массив объектов
let hierarchyStack = []; // Массив объектов

let endConnection = function(currentConnection) {   
    addConnToParent(currentConnection);
    addToHierarchy(currentConnection);
    addPointsToConnection (currentConnection);  
};

let addToHierarchy = function(currentConnection) {  
    currentConnection = {'foo': 'bar'};
    hierarchy.push(currentConnection);  
};
    
let addConnectionToParent = function(currentConnection) {
    let parentConn = hierarchyStack[hierarchyStack.length - 2];
    // ... some code
    parentConn.children.push(currentConnection); // children - массив объектов
};

let addPointsToConnection = function(connection) {
    // ... some code
    connection.points = schemaData.slice(2, 4);  // points - массив объектов
};
```

В каждом из методов изменяется переданный объект. В итоге в исходном методе после трёх методов исходный массив вообще может быть не похож на себя и изуродован до неузнаваемости.

---

А вот *Java*

```
class Test {
    public int hello = 111;
}

//....

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {
    Test a = new Test();
    System.out.println(a.hello);
    
    changeObjectValue(a);
    System.out.println(a.hello);
}

public static void changeObjectValue(Test b) {
    changeObjectValue2(b);
}

public static void changeObjectValue2(Test c) {
    changeObjectValue3(c);
}

public static void changeObjectValue3(Test d) {
    d.hello= 888;
}
```

Итог: через все эти методы этот объект "всплыл" изменённым. А таких методов может быть не один, в разных классах.

Если этот объект не используется в методах типа стримов - корректно ли такое использование и написание методов? Когда корректно возвращать изменённый аргумент, а не создавать сайд эффекты?

И в каких случаях **можно** изменить аргумент и это будет удобно?

Comment: Вообще тенденции современных фреймворков - Имутабельность

Comment: У каждой парадигмы есть свои плюсы и минусы. Строгая типизация, относящаяся в том числе и к функциям, неизбежно порождает излишнюю абстракцию (придется писать больше кода, для описания объектов). В JS зачастую это излишне усложнит программирование и соответственно увеличит время написания скриптов (как правило простых).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, это не плохая практика сама по себе. Вопрос в том, что вы и другие пользователи должны очевидным образом (лучше всего — из названия) понимать, что именно изменяет функция.

Если функция, к примеру, имеет сигнатуру

```
void Setup(Connection connection)
```

то очевидно, что ничего кроме побочного эффекта такая функция делать не может, что она настраивает соединение, и просто обязана изменять свой аргумент.

Если же функция *выглядит* как чистая функция, получает информацию лишь из аргументов, и возвращает результат лишь в виде возвращаемого значения, то и вести она должна соответствующим образом. Например, вот такая функция сложения:

```
Point operator+ (Point& other)
{
    this.X += other.X;
    this.Y += other.Y;
    return *this;
}
```

(знакомо, да?) совершенно никуда не годится.

Я бы предложил не смешивать концепции, и стараться делать функции такими:

- *либо* ваша функция производит лишь побочный эффект, тогда она типа void (или в крайнем случае bool, чтобы сигнализировать об успехе или неудаче, если вам не нравится идея с исключением),
- *либо* ваша функция чистая или почти чистая, вычисляет результат на основе входящих аргументов, и возвращает лишь возвращаемое значение.

Впрочем, это не догма: например, внешне чистая функция может внутри устроить кеширование. Главное, чтобы смешанная семантика не была публичным контрактом функции.